# renaming classes.jar to <project_name>.jar while building a library project in android ant

Tags: android, ant

I have an android application project A which depends on an Android Library project B. when i import both the projects in Eclipse,I've notice the Eclipse Builder (probably due to the ADT plugin), that the library project gets compiled and built as `b.jar` and stored inside the `bin\` folder of project B. It is referenced as b.jar in the classpath of A.

But, while building it with ant,the command `ant debug`,the library project B is compiled as `classes.jar`.

Is there a way to rename this file as .jar? I tried renaming it in the SDK build.xml,but then project A does not seem to resolve the classes defined in B. Also,the test project for B fails, since the Android dex compiler tries to search for the file classes.jar inside the `bin\` folder of the library project.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to look inside those ant scripts. The answer is in those scripts and only you have access to the scripts. Possibly eclipse supplies a definition when invoking ant, something you don't do when you compile the project manually.

Comment: @Jarekczek I'm pretty sure the eclipse adt package comes with its own builders, so i don't think it invokes ant for building this stuff. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I know nothing about Android or Eclipse, but since scripts are there, maybe they are used by Eclipse. Netbeans generates ant scripts for builds. They are very complicated, difficult to understand for Ant newbie.

Comment: @Jarekczek: Every Android developer has access to the Ant scripts--they're part of the SDK.  If you admittedly know nothing about Android or Eclipse, then please don't just make stuff up.

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom_rules.xml file in your project director.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules">
    <target name="-post-compile">
    <echo level="info">Renaming jar filename</echo>
    <move file="${out.library.jar.file}"tofile="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to rename the `jar` file is to add a `custom_rules.xml` file to the project, and override the right property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules">

  <property name="out.library.jar.file" location="bin/b.jar" />

</project>
```

If you look for this property name in the SDK's `build.xml`, you'll see why this works.

Note: I did not check from which API level the `custom_rules.xml` is supported by Android.

Answer (score 0):

I added an extra builder to the library project :
/bin/cp bin/classes.jar bin/${project_name}.jar

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is added a line to ant.properties:

```
out.library.jar.file=bin/b.jar
```

But if project B is referenced by project A in project-A/ant.properties like:

```
android.library.reference.1=/path/to/project-B
```

then compiler may complain that it cannot find symbols defined in project B.