# How to set artifact library root name

Tags: android, maven, jar, aar

context: android, jar, aar.

I have published my android artifact on a repo maven.
When I import it in my project in Android Studio, the artifact is showed as something like:

[image: no name library root]

All my classes is in the **classes.jar**

How can I changes the library root name to something like this **retrofit-2.7.0.jar** in the below image?

[image: named library root]

This is my script:

```
uploadArchives {
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {

        pom.groupId = GROUP
        pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
        pom.version = VERSION_NAME

        repository(url: getReleaseRepositoryUrl()) {
            authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
        }
        snapshotRepository(url: getSnapshotRepositoryUrl()) {
            authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
        }

        pom.project {
            name POM_NAME
            packaging POM_PACKAGING
            description POM_DESCRIPTION
            url POM_URL

            licenses {
                license {
                    name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                    url POM_LICENCE_URL
                    distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                    name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Update 2:
By applying

```
android {
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { // Rename output variant to whatever you want & it would get uploaded as library
            outputFileName = "name-of-your-library-artifact.extension" //I.e. myLib.jar
        }
    }
}
```

> the output artifact is renamed as `myLib.aar` but inside the aar, classes are still packaged as `classes.jar`

Comment: This question is similar but for ant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002326/

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue is not related to maven publish plugin but with how Android-Studio packages artifacts itself.

When you bundle or assemble **aar/jar**, Android-Studio by default generates names such as **classes.jar**.

You can try changing that by adding following code block to `android {}` DSL.

```
android {
    android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { // Rename output variant to whatever you want & it would get uploaded as library
            outputFileName = "name-of-your-library-artifact.extension" //I.e. myLib.jar
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. By applying the snippet, the build output file is renamed to `myLib.aar` but inside the package, the jar file is always named as `classes.jar`

Comment: Ohh I think then I don't know the exact solution but I can point you to that, you'll need to modify the task that generates source jar file. I think that task is `sourceJar` or something but don't know how to manipulate it.

Answer (score -1):

If you look into [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) by Jake Wharton you can in [gradle.properties](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/threetenabp/gradle.properties) see a few `POM_*` variables defined.

If you then open [gradle-mvn-push.gradle](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/blob/master/gradle/gradle-mvn-push.gradle), you can the usage of those three variables.
More about `gradle-mvn-push.gradle` file and how to use it you can read [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push).

Comment: I did use these 3 variables in `gradle.properties` already. I tried to import both `ThreeTenABP` and `ActionBar` but their library root name is showed as `classes.jar`.

Comment: `ThreeTenABP` is just an example in my answer.
Have you followed the instructions [here] (https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push) to publish your lib?

Comment: After publishing, the library is imported with the library root name `classes.jar`